Combining "LIKE" for multiple columns and values in SQL
I have a situation where I have a table containing manufacturers and product names, I want a query to look up product ids given a manufacturer and product name to search for
SELECT product_id
  FROM
    `product`
  WHERE
    product_id <> ''
    and lower(manufacturer) like '%acme%'
    and lower(product_name) like '%anvil%'

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow query multiple specific manufacturer and product names all in one query. For example I want to look up product ids for an "ACME Anvil" and a "DemoCO Dynamite".
The simplest way I could do this would be something along the lines of
SELECT product_id
  FROM
    `product`
  WHERE
    product_id <> ''
    and lower(manufacturer) like '%acme%'
    and lower(product_name) like '%anvil%'

UNION ALL

SELECT product_id
  FROM
    `product`
  WHERE
    product_id <> ''
    and lower(manufacturer) like '%democo%'
    and lower(product_name) like '%dynamite%'

but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution, especially when I could be looking up 20+ product/company combinations. Bear in mind that each combination is self-contained, so I don't want to get results for an "ACME Dynamite" from my query

Hi, What DBMS are you using?

The use of lower with the string you are searching for will result in 0 results every time.

This part... I could be looking up 20+ product/company combinations clearly means you need to improve your DB structure. Never try to create a query with such many combinations, that will be horrible slow and horrible bad to maintain. Rather create a mapping table which holds the combinations and simply join that table in your query.

@VvdL In SQL Server, that would depend on the collation being used. In any case, the statement doesn't make much sense.

An alternative is using OR statements. Be careful of using the correct parentheses though.
SELECT product_id
  FROM
    `product`
  WHERE
    product_id <> ''
    AND (
          (lower(manufacturer) like '%acme%' and lower(product_name) like '%anvil%')
       OR (lower(manufacturer) like '%democo%' and lower(product_name) like '%dynamite%')
     --OR (lower(manufacturer) like '%aaa%' and lower(product_name) like '%bbb%')
     --OR (lower(manufacturer) like '%xxx%' and lower(product_name) like '%yyy%') 
    )


No, no, no! Did you read they need 20 or more combinations? Writing them out with 20, 30 or 100 OR would become one of the worst queries ever.

...depending on the dbms used.

this is the best OP is gonna get.

If you realy need to filter the data like in the question then to make it a bit more readable/maintainable you could use a cte to define lookup values (... or  fetch them from somewhere if possible ...) and then use join's ON conditions as the filter:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table product AS
Select 1 as id, 'AAA Company' as manufacturer, 'Product 11A from AAA' as product_name UNION ALL 
Select 2, 'Production Co. BBB', 'Product BB22 from BBB' UNION ALL 
Select 3, 'CCC Ltd.', 'Product C3C from CCC' UNION ALL 
Select 4, 'DDD Repairs', 'Product D4DD from DDD';
--
Select * From product;




ID
MANUFACTURER
PRODUCT_NAME




1
AAA Company
Product 11A from AAA


2
Production Co. BBB
Product BB22 from BBB


3
CCC Ltd.
Product C3C from CCC


4
DDD Repairs
Product D4DD from DDD



--  Oracle, MySQL, MariaDB (tested)
WITH
  lookups AS
    ( Select 'aaa' as manufacturer, '11a' as product_name Union All
      Select 'bbb', '333' Union All
      Select 'ccc', 'c3'
      -- more lookups hardcoded or fetched from some other database object
      --
   )
Select    p.* 
From      product p 
Inner Join lookups l ON( LOWER(p.manufacturer) LIKE Concat('%', LOWER(l.manufacturer), '%') And 
                         LOWER(p.product_name) LIKE Concat('%', LOWER(l.product_name), '%') 
                       )

R e s u l t :



ID
MANUFACTURER
PRODUCT_NAME




1
AAA Company
Product 11A from AAA


3
CCC Ltd.
Product C3C from CCC



OR
--  Oracle, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite (tested)
WITH
  lookups AS
    ( Select 'aaa' as manufacturer, '11a' as product_name Union All
      Select 'bbb', '333' Union All
      Select 'ccc', 'c3'
      -- more lookups hardcoded or fetched from some other database object
      --
   )
Select    p.* 
From      product p 
Inner Join lookups l ON(InStr(LOWER(p.manufacturer), LOWER(l.manufacturer)) > 0 And 
                        InStr(LOWER(p.product_name), LOWER(l.product_name)) > 0) 

R e s u l t :



ID
MANUFACTURER
PRODUCT_NAME




1
AAA Company
Product 11A from AAA


3
CCC Ltd.
Product C3C from CCC



NOTE:
The code above was tested with a few databases - you may need to adjust it to your db sql dialect - something like - instead of INSTR() function use POSITION() for Postgres or CHARINDEX() for sql-server...
fiddle
